# "go ON / TO / ONTO the list"

Tags: prepositions

In the following situation, which of the three prepositions would you use?

A friend of yours makes you listen to a song that you like so much you say:

> This goes straight **on** my playlist.

Now my question is, is **on** the right preposition to use here? Or should be **onto** or **to**?

Comment: Are you using a specific variant of English? I don't think "this goes straight on/onto/to my playlist" would be my AmE preference, instead something more like "I'm adding this to my playlist"... "straight on" for some reason sounds very British to me... I guess the whole "straight away" thing.

Comment: It depends on how you perceive a playlist. Thirty years ago the list would have been on paper, so I would have used *onto* as it would be written on a flat piece of paper. But nowadays it is probably data on an electronic device, so I would use *in/into* since technically it is new data is added to existing data.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

I would say that the following seems more frequent for your example:

> this goes straight *to* my playlist

If you are adding something, you may say:

> add this track to my playlist.

If you are telling that some track isn't there, you may say:

> this is not on my playlist.

*onto* is generally used when there's a physical movement.

> The jockey jumped *onto* the horse.

Comment: Would you say 'this goes straight on my playlist' is wrong grammatically speaking?

Comment: @SoumyaGhosh The most usual preposition here is *on*; another one (also pretty normal but maybe not as common, probably because it's a syllable longer) is *onto*. *To* is almost never used. See [this](https://corpus.byu.edu/iweb/?c=iweb&q=66406688) (notice that pretty much all the results with *to* don't match the meaning you wish to convey). That said, the most common way to say this (at least in AmE) would be *this **is going** straight on my playlist*, while your version isn't very popular (but is acceptable).